# Substring test within DataTable.Select()

Tags: c#, select, datatable, substring

I have a DataTable with results already pulled down from a back end.
I want to do a DataTable.Select(), but the criteria is based on a SUBSTRING of one of the columns.

Is there syntax to use in the Select() method that allows for substring of a column test, or do I have to do it the hard way -- scan each row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the LIKE operator in the expression given to Select():

```
table.Select("ItemName LIKE '*product*'")
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use linq, like the following example:

```
var x = from c in table.AsEnumerable()
        select c.Field<string>("MyColumn").Substring(index, length);
```

or

```
var x = from c in table.AsEnumerable()
        select c.Field<string>("MyColumn").Contains("MySearchString");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring.

```
DataRow[] selectRowsWithSubstring;
selectRowsWithSubstring = datatable.Select("substring(column, start, length) = value");
```